# How to handle an error on ajax login form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have several login forms that use ajax, but now when information is wrong the page just refreshes. I want to catch some keyword/variable from my php, right now I am echoing 'error', and I want some alert on the page with no refresh. Here's my current js. When I submit, a login object is created and then the login method performed, if successful it redirects to a dashboard if not it echos 'error' and then how can I accomplish what I need with javascript?

```
<script>
$('#doctor_login').on("submit", function(e){


frmReg = document.getElementById("doctor_login");


    if(frmReg.user_name.value == "")     { alert("<?php echo _USERNAME_EMPTY_ALERT; ?>"); frmReg.user_name.focus(); return false;        
    }else if(frmReg.password.value == ""){ alert("<?php echo _PASSWORD_IS_EMPTY; ?>"); frmReg.password.focus(); return false;        
    }else{
            $.ajax({

    type:'POST',
    url: '../page/handler/handler_ajax_login.php',
    data: $(this).serialize()
    }


    });
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure but maybe you have to use `e.preventDefault();` at the onsubmit function, so the page doesn't refresh.

Comment: You have to look for ajax events like "success", "error", "complete" and "beforeSend" ;-) : http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: The PHP script should return a value that indicates whether the login was successful or not. Then the AJAX callback function can display an error if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery exposes a `error` callback on the `$.ajax` method, as documented on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: '../page/handler/handler_ajax_login.php',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
}
```

To trigger the error callback, you must return a `400` or `500` range HTTP code.

```
<?php

header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
```

Comment: I think `error:` should be used for low-level problems, like network errors or URL not found. To report a login error, the PHP should return a success indicator in the response, perhaps using a JSON object.

Comment: Say the API is following RESTful principles. In that case, only 200 series responses will be returned for successful requests, ergo incorrect logins will return a non-200 series code. It really depends on how the system is designed.

Comment: Different tastes for different people, having standardised designs for code helps interoperability between different clients and APIs. Really just design choices of the project and developer.

Comment: whenever I use the error callback it always does whatever is in that function, whether the login works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate the data if it is equal to 'error' in the success function.

```
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url: '../page/handler/handler_ajax_login.php',
data: $(this).serialize(),
success: function(data){
  if(data == "error"){
     console.log("error");
  }
}
});
```

Comment: I tried echoing and doing it with session variables like                                   (error = $_SESSION['error']  if(error == 1){do stuff}                                        and the condition is met, but nothing in the success callback will do anything

Answer (score 0):

you can use the success and error options
Here is an example

```
     var yurl = ""
     var furl = "proxy.php";
     $.ajax({
         url: furl,
         data: { url: escape(yurl) },
         dataType: "html",
         success: function (data) {
             $("#homecon").load("proxy.php .content");
         },
         error: function (xhr, err, e) { 
         alert("error");
         }
     });
     return false;
```

Comment: You need to explain how to cause a login failure to result in an AJAX error, like @Carey did in his answer.